# Sci-fi novel set in future Japan/Asia about an individual and company mergers - or he worked for a tech company

Tags: story-identification, novel

Sci-fi novel set in future Japan/Asia; I was given the book in the 90s. I believe it was about an individual and company mergers - or he worked for a tech company?

I believe the cover was silver and black and the title started with a letter "Y" - I could never pronounce it as a child.

Asian author I think as well.

Comment: There is very little to go on here for what this could be, is there anything else about the story that you can remember that you could [edit] in?

Comment: @user14111 I'm guessing future + Asia + tech could lead to some sci-fi but right now it's not obvious

Comment: All the future stuff is on-topic by default, assuming that it's a different society and not just 2020 with 2018 fashions or whatever.

Answer (score 3):

I actually figured it out, I was listening to a lot of Cyberpunk playlists and mix's on YouTube recently - just started to enjoy the tunes while at work - then it occurred to me that the novel was rather cyberpunk, so I googled “cyberpunk novel in japan” – and there it was *[Idoru](http://www.williamgibsonbooks.com/books/idoru.asp)* by William Gibson.

I was pretty off in my description.

Comment: Don't forget to come back and accept your answer, and possibly improve your question to help future visitors that may be looking for this novel. Welcome to the site!